# Routing between two projects in angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I was looking at an article about how an Angular app was routing between two projects.

I have two projects called *presentation.web* and *security.web*.

In *security.web* I have controllers for an authentication service. Once the user has been authenticated the page needs to be redirected to the home page in *presentation.web*.

How do I achieve this by using a single app? Or how can I route between two apps? I'm using visual studio 2013 to develop my project (developing an AngularJS app with C#)

I have controller for registration and sign in under security.web(highlighted in screenshot) project

[image: have controller for registration and sign in]

and i have home controller and todocontroller under presentation.web project(highlighted in screenshot) when the user was signedin the page has to be redirected to todoManager.

signincontroller:

```
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = data.refresh_token;

            $cookieStore.put('_Token', data.access_token);
            window.location = '#/todomanager';
        })
```

[image: home controller]

now what i want is the app which i have the routing to the pages in normal way what we using but i want to route the modules between these two projects. is it possible to route the module in like below?

```
//================================================
// Routes
//================================================
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'App/Home',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/register', {
    templateUrl: 'App/Register',
    controller: 'registerCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/signin/:message?', {
    templateUrl: 'App/SignIn',
    controller: 'signInCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/todomanager', {
    templateUrl: 'App/TodoManager',
    controller: 'todoManagerCtrl'
});`app.run(['$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', function ($http, $cookies, $cookieStore) {
//If a token exists in the cookie, load it after the app is loaded, so that the application can maintain the authenticated state.
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('_Token');
$http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = $cookieStore.get('_RefreshToken');}]);`
```

here im getting the token in presentation.web

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore) {

$rootScope.logout = function () {

    $http.post('/api/Account/Logout')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = null;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = null;
            $cookieStore.remove('_Token');
            $cookieStore.remove('_RefreshToken');
            $rootScope.username = '';
            $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
            window.location = '#/signin';
        });

}

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    if ($http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken != null) {
        var params = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken;
        $http({
            url: '/Token',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: params
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = data.refresh_token;

            $cookieStore.put('_Token', data.access_token);
            $cookieStore.put('_RefreshToken', data.refresh_token);

            $http.get('/api/WS_Account/GetCurrentUserName')
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data != "null") {
                        $rootScope.username = data.replace(/["']{1}/gi, "");//Remove any quotes from the username before pushing it out.
                        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                    }
                    else
                        $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
                });


        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
        });
    }
});
```

}]);

or what can i do for routing?

Comment: Please post your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking or what your specific problem is

Comment: if they are two separate projects, they are two separate pages, with two separate urls, and routing from one to the other would be no different from routing from your app to any other 3rd party url.  I'm not really clear on what the goal is here, though, since you can't share data between these two app instances either....

Comment: in other words, if *security.web* is writing a login token to the cookie store, there isn't any way for *presentation.web* to access that login token...

Comment: i have updated my question and how do i use 3rd party url to route between two app instances?

Comment: the premise of your question is still flawed.  using two different angular applications is not going to achieve the result you are wanting.  You *cannot* authenticate with one application and then use the authentication results with another application.

Comment: so i can use only one application to achieve this right?

Comment: forget about the code what i updated here.. i need a clarification on passing the authenticated token between two application.. for example i have authentication service in one application and home page in another application, once i have logged in to the application the token need to be passed to application which is having the home page (routing) and when the page got session out the application needs to be redirected to the application which is having the login page.

Comment: any one please reply ASAP